# not using strcmp properly in C

Tags: c, string, binary, strcmp

I wrote this method to find the biggest power of 2 that will fit in a given decimal. The decimal is in char array format to avoid input overflow error with number storage. Powers of 2 are calculated with pow(2, power) format of float  ie. 8.000000 This number is then sent to a method to remove the period and the 0's that trail. ie. 8.000000 turns into 8

```
1  #include <string.h>
2  #include <stdio.h>
3  #include <stdlib.h>
4  #include <memory.h>
5  #include <math.h>
6
7   int i;
16
17  void removeFloatZeros(char *floatvalue)
18  {
19      char *ptr = strchr(floatvalue, '.');
20      *ptr = '\0';
21  }
22
45
173 char *decimalToBinary(char *decimal)
174 {
176     int x;
177     double power = 0;
178     char *binary = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1024);
179     char *twosPower = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1024);
180
181     /* What is the greatest power of 2 that will fit into the decimal? */
182     for(x = 0; x <= 30; x++)
183     {
184         power = pow(2.0, x);
185         snprintf(twosPower, 1023, "%f", power);
186         removeFloatZeros(twosPower);
189         printf("strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = %d\n", strcmp(twosPower, decimal));  
190         memset(twosPower, '\0', 1023);
191     }
214 }
215
216 int main(int argc, char*argv[])
217 {
218     char *dec1 = argv[1];
219     decimalToBinary(dec1);
220     return 1;
221 }
222
```

For example if I input 20 into argv[1] it will output:

```
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1  
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = 1
strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = -1
```

Where am I going wrong with this? Also, ignore the ending condition for the for loop. It's supposed to output all 1's before the 6th iteration and all -1's on the 6th and after the 6th iteration.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the actual strings you're comparing, whether it be in a debugger or by printing them along with the result of `strcmp`? I don't think `strcmp` is broken.

Comment: Claiming that a mainstream library function like `strcmp()` is misbehaving is a mark of a tyro.  The problem must be in how you are using it, not in a bedrock function like that.

Comment: After many years of programming, my own attitude in such situations is always and without a second thought: "I must be making a mistake". Every other year I manage to surprise myself... :-)

Comment: Also, both of your mallocs are wrong. Use either `sizeof(char)` or nothing (just 1024).

Comment: Yes I have tried printing them side by side next to each other and they seem fine. And I don't claim that it's not working correctly I just want you to know that there's something I'm doing that is wrong.

Comment: Personally, I prefer nothing.  `sizeof(char)` is `1`, so why bother typing it?

Comment: Moreover, `sizeof(char)` implies that you don't know what units `sizeof` measures in. It's analogous to writing `how_many_meters_in(1_meter)`.

Answer (score 2):

strcmp return values:

A zero value indicates that both strings are equal.

A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in str1 than in str2.

And a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

Your input: 20
Your first iteration of the loop: twosPower = "1"
strcmp("20", "1")

The first character doesn't match and has a smaller value in str2 ("1") than in str1 ("2") -> return negative value.

The rest of the iterations should explain themselves...

Also, Edit:

```
printf("strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = %d\n", strcmp(twosPower, decimal));
```

Your printf format string states the opposite of what you're doing in the parameter.

Edit:

```
str1    str2    
1       20  First char that differs is '1' vs. '2'. '1' (ASCII 49) is smaller than '2' (ASCII 50), 49 - 50 = -1 = return value
2       20  First char that differs is '\0' vs. '0'. '\0' (ASCII 0) is smaller than '0' (ASCII 48), 0 - 48 = -48 = return value
4       20  First char that differs is '4' vs. '2'. '4' (ASCII 52) is greather than '2' (ASCII 50), 52 - 50 = 2 = return value
8       20  First char that differs is '8' vs. '2'. '4' (ASCII 56) is greather than '2' (ASCII 50), 56 - 50 = 6 = return value
16      20  First char that differs is '1' vs. '2'. '1' (ASCII 49) is smaller than '2' (ASCII 50), 49 - 50 = -1 = return value

... and so on ...
```

Maybe this output helps a bit more

Furthermore, your method of finding the greatest power of 2 in a number is flawed since strcmp's return value is just dependent on the FIRST char that differs.
So strcmp("2", "16") and strcmp("200000000", "16") would always return the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This cleaned up version of your code produces the output shown:

```
$ ./xx 20
strcmp(1, 20) = -1
strcmp(2, 20) = -48
strcmp(4, 20) = 2
strcmp(8, 20) = 6
strcmp(16, 20) = -1
strcmp(32, 20) = 1
strcmp(64, 20) = 4
strcmp(128, 20) = -1
strcmp(256, 20) = 5
strcmp(512, 20) = 3
strcmp(1024, 20) = -1
strcmp(2048, 20) = 52
strcmp(4096, 20) = 2
strcmp(8192, 20) = 6
strcmp(16384, 20) = -1
strcmp(32768, 20) = 1
strcmp(65536, 20) = 4
strcmp(131072, 20) = -1
strcmp(262144, 20) = 6
strcmp(524288, 20) = 3
strcmp(1048576, 20) = -1
strcmp(2097152, 20) = 57
strcmp(4194304, 20) = 2
strcmp(8388608, 20) = 6
strcmp(16777216, 20) = -1
strcmp(33554432, 20) = 1
strcmp(67108864, 20) = 4
strcmp(134217728, 20) = -1
strcmp(268435456, 20) = 6
strcmp(536870912, 20) = 3
strcmp(1073741824, 20) = -1
$
```

Suffice to say that there are a lot of small changes.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void removeFloatZeros(char *floatvalue)
{
    char *ptr = strchr(floatvalue, '.');
    *ptr = '\0';
}

static void decimalToBinary(char *decimal)
{
    int x;
    double power = 0;
    char *twosPower = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 1024);

    /* What is the greatest power of 2 that will fit into the decimal? */
    for(x = 0; x <= 30; x++)
    {
        power = pow(2.0, x);
        snprintf(twosPower, 1023, "%f", power);
        removeFloatZeros(twosPower);
        printf("strcmp(%s, %s) = %d\n", twosPower, decimal, strcmp(twosPower, decimal));  
        //printf("strcmp(decimal, twosPower) = %d\n", strcmp(twosPower, decimal));  
        memset(twosPower, '\0', 1023);
    }
    free(twosPower);
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        decimalToBinary(argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Showing the compared values makes things a lot easier to understand.  You need to free memory (or use automatic arrays).  You need to use headers.  The `static` declarations aren't 100% necessary, but mean I don't get any warnings when I compile under my über-fussy compiler settings.

But the key change is printing out the values that are being compared - it makes sense of the numbers from `strcmp()`.

(Consider adding an appropriate number of leading zeroes before doing your comparison.)

Comment: printf("strcmp(%s, %s) = %d\n", decimal, twosPower, strcmp(twosPower, decimal));
Order of strcmp and printf arguments do not reflect what's actually done.